# Geom_line between all points

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom

I want a line between all my detections points, how can I get this?

[image: Geomline]

When I run:

```
AT.data_posisjon %>%
  filter(ID %in% Tag_84) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=DateTime,y=Array,color=Section))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()
```

I got only line between points in the same section, but I want a line between different sections too.

Answer (score 0):

Your `geom_point` and `geom_line` inherits its aesthetics from the "global" one provided in the `ggplot`-call. In other words, the rows in the data frame  gets divided into groups, based on your `Section`, for both `geom_point` and `geom_line`.

One solution is to move the color-specification to to geom_point, ie.

```
ggplot(aes(x=DateTime, y=Array)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=Section)) +
  geom_line()
```

This the color of the line connecting all the dots is black -- the same color for all rows.

If you want the line connecting the dots to have the same color as the dots, you have to ask yourself: A line that connects two dots of different color, what color should the line have?

If you can "nøjes" with "intersection"-lines being black, we can draw colored lines on top of the black ones:

```
ggplot(aes(x=DateTime, y=Array)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=Section)) +
  geom_line() +  # black line between all dots
  geom_line(aes(color=Section)) # a *new* set of lines, which are drawn *on top*, but only "within" each section.
```